# Как использовать индексы в Mysql в связке с PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Киньте ссылок хороших, а то я погуглил, почитал, не понял нифига как их правильно использовать.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Непосредcтвенное использование и создание индексов не является задачей приложения - вам не нужно особым образом что-то писать в PHP коде, что с ними работать. Индексы предназначены для улучшения производительности базы данных при выполнении запросов, включающих в условии поле, на которое создан индекс (это грубо говоря, подробнее см. [документацию MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html), например). Т.е. вы смотрите на приложение, смотрите на логи, ищете медленные и частые запросы и создаете соответствующие индексы. Приложение не знает, есть индексы или нет - их использует БД. На счет статей - поищите "когда использовать индексы", [вот](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/mysql_index.txt.html), например, первая статья.

Comment: ой, сюда :)

Answer (score 2):

Хорошая статья про выбор колонок для  индексации: [Как выбрать колонки для индексирования в MySQL](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/06/09/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD/)